# how can I get the affiliation symbol on top of the second author?

Tags: author

I really like the affiliation symbol on top of the second author, that little thing looks like a cross. However, there is only one author in my paper, how can I get that little cross symbol with only adding one author?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\title{Title}
\stepcounter{footnote}
\author{Author\thanks{Footnote text.}}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```